# How to use `while read -r line` while also checking if another file is not empty in BASH?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a while loop, simplified like this:

```
while read -r line
do
    (delete some lines from file2.txt)
done < file.txt
```

If `file2.txt` is empty, then this while loop has no need to function any longer.

In other words, I need this:

```
while read -r line AND file2.txt IS NOT EMPTY
do
    (delete some lines from file2.txt
done < file.txt
```

I've tried to combined `while read -r line` with `-s file2.txt`, but the result does not work:

```
while [ read -r line ] || [ -s file2.txt ]
do
    (delete some lines from file2.txt)
done < file.txt
```

How can I use this while loop to read the lines in a file while also checking that another file is not empty?

Comment: You could put an `if (file2.txt is empty check) ; then break ; fi` in the original `while` loop right after the `(delete some lines from file2.txt)`. I'm not sure how you're deleting lines from `file2.txt`, so unsure as to what "empty" check you would want to make.

Comment: I used `sed -i "/$line/d" ./file2.txt` to remove content from `file2.txt`, which happens while the while loop is going. What happens is, `file2.txt` becomes empty fairly soon, but the `while loop` keeps going for several minutes unnecessarily. If I put the `if` conditional inside the `while` conditional, I don't think the script will be sped up.

Comment: @Village Is something else adding lines to this file?  Are you implementing a queue?  If you are you may want to consider using a fifo (see `mkfifo`) instead.  I'm just not sure if the `sed -i` is atomic enough

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Combine the read and the test as:

```
while read -r line && [ -s file2.txt ]
do
  # (delete some lines from file2.txt)
  echo "$line"
done <file.txt
```

This will check, before every iteration of the loop, whether `file2.txt` is non-empty.

Comment: I would move the `[` test to before the `read` expression so as to avoid unnecessarily consuming another line of stdin.

Answer (score 3):

A *useless use of cat* would simplify things here:

```
while read -r line
do
    (delete some lines from file2.txt)
done < <(test -s file2.txt && cat file.txt)
```

---

```
$ cat file.txt
foo
bar
baz
$ cat file2.txt
something
$ while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(test -s file2.txt && cat file.txt)
foo
bar
baz
$ > file2.txt
$ while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(test -s file2.txt && cat file.txt)
$
```

Comment: Not so useless if it's actually useful, is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
while read -r lf1 && [[ -s "path/to/file2" ]] && read -r lf2 <&3; do 
   echo "$lf1"; echo "$lf2"
done <file1 3<file2
```

Just a sample, you can add your own code in the `while` block.

#### Test:

```
<~/Temp>$ cat file1
line from file1
line2 from file1
```

```
<~/Temp>$ cat file2
I am not empty
Yep not empty
```

```
<~/Temp>$ while read -r lf1 && [[ -s "/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/file2" ]] && read -r lf2 <&3; do echo "$lf1"; echo "$lf2"; done <file1 3<file2
line from file1
I am not empty
line2 from file1
Yep not empty
```

```
<~/Temp>$ >file2
```

```
<~/Temp>$ while read -r lf1 && [[ -s "/Volumes/Data/jaypalsingh/Temp/file2" ]] && read -r lf2 <&3; do echo "$lf1"; echo "$lf2"; done <file1 3<file2
<~/Temp>$
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just do

```
while read -r line
do
    [ ! -s file2.txt ] && break
    # (delete some lines from file2.txt)
done <file.txt
```

Strictly speaking, my solution doesn't do anything different or better than any of the other solutions, but it's a matter of personal taste. I don't like mixing in other conditions for a loop that's doing something as simple as reading lines from a file. I find it makes the code less readable. Others will no doubt disagree, and perhaps even suggest that relying on a `break` inside the loop is bad practice, but I find that it allows me to quickly grasp what's going on without having to slow down and mentally process the conditional, much like you stop when you see a stop sign in your peripheral vision, without having to look directly at the sign and read the letters "STOP" to understand it. Things like `while read -r line` are such common idioms that they are essentially the programming equivalent of common street signs. You recognize them instantly without having to mentally parse them. Anyway, like I said, this is just my personal take on it. Feel free to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

just a little optimizing the answer given by Joe

```
while [ -s file2.txt ] && read -r line
do
  # (delete some lines from file2.txt)
done <file.txt
```